# gsutil - issue with cp, rsync when using federated user AWS keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm attempting a simple rsync (or cp) from AWS S3 to GCP Storage. 
For e.g.

```
gsutil rsync -d -r -n s3://mycustomer-src gs://mycustomer-target
```

I get an error message as below when attempting this on a VM on GCP.
Note that if I install aws cli on the VM, then I can access / browse AWS S3 contents just fine. The AWS credentials are stored in ~/.aws/credentials file.

```
Building synchronization state...
Caught non-retryable exception while listing s3://musiclab-etl-dev/: AccessDeniedException: 403 InvalidAccessKeyId
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>ASIAJ3XGCQ7RGZYPD5UA</AWSAccessKeyId><RequestId>CE8919045C68DEC4</RequestId><HostId>i7oMBM61US3FyePJka8O+rjoHSo1rIZbRGnVZvIGkjEVPh6lXdbp03pZOtJ68F3pPdAAW1UvF5s=</HostId></Error>
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

Is this a bug in gsutil ? Any workarounds or tips appreciated.

NOTE - The client's AWS account is setup for federated access and requires using AWS keys as obtained using a script similar to this-
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-implement-a-general-solution-for-federated-apicli-access-using-saml-2-0/
The AWS keys are set to expire when the session token expires.

If I use a different AWS account (no federation) with typical AWS keys (non-expiring), the rsync (or cp) works fine.

Comment: It seems to me that 'gsutil' does not account for the aws_session_token that is also used for credential validation in addition to the aws_access_key_id and the aws_secret_access_key

Comment: It looks like this issue exists when trying out the Cloud Storage Transfer feature as well.

Answer (score 13):

It appears that gsutil still uses the legacy `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` instead of `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`. If your script doesn't set it up automatically, you can do it manually like this:

```
export AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

After this you should be able to use gsutil normally.